# Why js XHR get code from php local file instead of executing it?

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, json, xmlhttprequest

I have nodejs server and on the client side to avoid CORS error I have a php file with file_get_contents which echo json from the different domain

```php
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('http://localhost/pixi/multidymy/getRanking.php');
echo $json;
```

The problem is my js is getting the php code instead of json (php code is not executed). If I open the php file from URL it works fine. Am I missing some headers? What's going on? There is no error displayed in the console

```
const ranking = document.getElementById("ranking");
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "/ranking.php", true); //<-- its in the local folder
xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
    if (this.status === 200) {
        console.log('Result:');
        console.log(this.responseText);
        ranking.innerHTML = this.responseText;
    } else {
        ranking.innerHTML = "error";
    }
})
xhr.send(null);
```

Comment: How are you running the javascript? If the javascript is running in a local file `file:///` instead of `http://`, then `ranking.php` will be loaded via the file as well

Comment: I am running local nodeJS server on port 3000
http://localhost:3000

Comment: What does the url say when you're accessing this javascript?

Comment: http://fx-team.fulara.com/team/adam/ss.png hope this screen shot helps

Comment: What do you mean by `my js is getting the php code instead of json`?

Comment: I don't know much about php, but it seems like you need a php server for the code to run, right? If your server is a nodeJS server, you problably need to use some PHP lib on the nodeJS server to give it ability to run PHP code. Can you post more info about your nodeJS server setup?

Comment: `file_get_contents` puts all of the contents of the file into a string. If the file is a php file, with php code in it, it won't be json. `file_get_contents` does not execute the php file; it just gets its contents and returns it in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Your XMLHTTPReqest is being sent to NodeJS server via port 3000. Your php is under port 80. In the end your response is coming from nodejs and the server running php.  You can not change port of XMLHttpReqest because of cross site scripting. I would suggest you use nodejs to retrieve your file via http request.

Check link below on how to do that with built in http request.

https://nodejs.org/api/http.html

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarification. I did it that way and now it works. I only wonder why it is designed that way

Answer (score -1):

Would you please check nodeJs code and put the below line into the service call.

```
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type, sessionid");
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
```

for example function name like **getAllData**

```
getAllData(req, res) {

    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With,content-type, sessionid");
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    .
    .

    .
    res.json({ 'IsSuccess' : false, 'StatusCode' : 500 , 'Message' : err.message, 'Data' : '' });
}
```